# I am trying to apply .apply for a column in pandas but it throws TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to apply .apply for a column in pandas with

```
 import pandas as pd
ids = pd.DataFrame({
    'Id':['ABCD0000000001', 'ABCD0000000002', 'ABCD0000000003','ABCD0000000004','ABCD0000000004'],

}
)

ids['Id']=ids['Id'].apply(lambda x: x[:2] + 'X' * (len(x) - 2) + x[-1])
```

It works fine for above dataset, But it throws an error for the original data set.

Error for original data set:

**TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable**

Comment: Hi. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: @jezrael will edit it

Comment: @jezrael please check.

Comment: How working `ids['Id']=ids['Id'].fillna('').apply(lambda x: x[:2] + 'X' * (len(x) - 2) + x[-1])` ? Because it seems some missing values

Comment: @jezrael throws IndexError: string index out of range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can add filtering by missing values:

```
ids['Id1']=ids['Id'].apply(lambda x: x[:2] + 'X' * (len(x) - 2) + x[-1] if  pd.notnull(x) else x)
```

Or:

```
ids['Id1']= [x[:2] + 'X' * (len(x) - 2) + x[-1] if  pd.notnull(x) else x for x in ids['Id']]
```